# I cannot ping a LAN machine from host configured with a Linux bridge

Tags: linux, networking, debian, bridge

I want to setup a mini lab to play with Bare-metal Kubernetes using the devices I have (A laptop host and a Raspberry Pi 3) and here is what I am basically trying to do:

[image: Network Topology]

I am trying to connect the KVM virtual machines, the host and the Raspberry Pi into the same virtual network. I came up with the idea of using a Linux bridge. I added the host's physical NIC to the bridge and I created the KVM VMs with a bridged interface. I assigned static IP addresses (192.168.123.0/24) to all the interfaces (VMs, host NIC, bridge and Raspberry Pi). The VMs and the host are reaching each other but I cannot ping the Raspberry Pi node. When I disable the bridge, the host can reach the Raspberry Pi node without any problem. What am I missing here, please ?

PS: The host is running Debian 9.

Bridge config:

```
auto kube-br
iface kube-br inet static
    address 192.168.123.127
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports enp2s0f0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

Comment: Do you have some other access to the Raspberry Pi? Can you check whether its `ip neigh` or `arp -an` reports the correct MAC address for the host (i.e. it should show the bridge, not the physical Ethernet interface)?

Comment: @grawity Yes I have just checked, it is right.

Comment: when everything is running can you run `brctl show` & `brctl show kube-br`

Answer (score 0):

The steps to make a correct setup are the following:

1. Create a Linux virtual bridge br0 (`brctl` or through `/etc/network/interfaces`)
2. Assign an IP address to the bridge.
3. Bring up the bridge and the host's NIC but don't assign an IP to the host's NIC (`ip link set NIC up`)
4. Configure the KVM guests to use the previous bridge (`--network bridge=br0` or through `virsh edit DOMAIN` if VM already exists)
5. Start KVM domains, bring up their NICs and assign IP addresses.
6. The VMs and the Raspberry Pi should all be connected to the same network now.

More details at: [Libvirt - Bridged Network](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/bridged-network.html)